# store.dispatch(sagaActionForAsync) not working due to unable to define Action

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I use store.dispatch to call the action of Saga.
However I get the following error and cannot run store.dispatch.

```
Argument of type 'IncrementAsyncAction' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IncrementAction | DecrementAction'.
  Type 'IncrementAsyncAction' is not assignable to type 'DecrementAction'.
    Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
      Type '"INCREMENT_ASYNC"' is not assignable to type '"DECREMENT"'.ts(2345)
```

I could call it with useDispatch of React-Redux.
How do I make store.dispatch aware of the action?

https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-banach-1f756

Comment: did you find any solution or workaround ?